# Тестирование микросервиса, работающего с бинарными данными

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, тестирование, rabbitmq, микросервисы

Необходимо написать интеграционные и модульные тесты для микросервиса на NodeJS.

Сервис слушает очередь rabbitmq, получает ссылку на видео файл в удаленной файловой системе, перекодирует его в различные форматы с помощью пакета fluent-ffmpeg и отправляет в другую очередь ссылки на созданные файлы вместе с информацией о видео.

Есть ли способ покрыть этот сервис тестами? Допускается ли хранение в репозитории сервиса примеров видео, получаемых на вход? Куда сохранять файлы, созданные ffmpeg при тестировании?

Answer (score 1):

Добро утро.

> Есть ли способ покрыть этот сервис тестами?

Конечно.

> Допускается ли хранение в репозитории сервиса примеров видео, получаемых на вход?

Видимо, вопрос о хранении тестовых данных. Тут как сами решите. Можно хранить на удаленном сервере и сливать перед прогоном, но это время. Вообще, думаю в данном случае стоит заморочиться и подготовить видео файлы не большой длины (и соответственно размера) и хранить их с кодом тестов.

> Куда сохранять файлы, созданные ffmpeg при тестировании?

Можно сохранять в tmp. Прелесть в том, что после перезагрузки системы ненужные данные будут удалены.